# Random Float against an specific amount with 100 days php

Tags: php, laravel, random

I am trying to generate random values against '100' amount of value for 100 days. I am trying this way with for loop:

```
        $total_days = 100;
        $total_amount = 100;
        $arr = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i)
        {
            $arr[] = rand(0.0, 1000.0);
        }

        $actual_sum = array_sum($arr);

        for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i)
        {
            $arr[$i] *= $total_amount /$actual_sum;
            //echo $arr[$i]."<BR><BR>";
            
            $value = $arr[$i];

            $genpackageroi = array(
                'userid' => $userid,
                'pkgid' => $pkgid,
                'pkgcount' => $pkcount,
                'amount' => $value,
                'created_at' => $created_at,
                'updated_at' => $updated_at,
            );

            DB::table('genpackageroi')->insert($genpackageroi);

        }
```

The random generated value is like 0.1245444 OR 1.1245545, lots of numbers after decimal. While I just want this to be generated in float value like 1.21, 0.10, 2.25 like so. I it possible to do that?

Comment: doesnt applying round function here ( `'amount' => round($value, 2),`) work for you?

Comment: this is working for after the number generates. But I want to generate the random numbers in round numbers. Because It dose not matches the actual amount after generating all the random numbers if we sum the generated random numbers. Like if I generates the random numbers for amount of 100, then the sum of all generated random numbers should 100. This is what actually I want.

Comment: Oh, I am not a maths major so I wouldnt know for sure, but it feels like what you are trying to achieve will be difficult. I can think of a hacky approach though. Let me think of a solution and post.

Comment: posted an answer. do please let me know if it works. you would probably need to refactor to standardise.

Comment: @user3532758 thanks for the solution I have checked the solution you posted and commented there regarding the solution plz have a look on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to generate the random numbers in round numbers. Because It
> dose not matches the actual amount after generating all the random
> numbers if we sum the generated random numbers. Like if I generates
> the random numbers for amount of 100, then the sum of all generated
> random numbers should 100. This is what actually I want.

What I gathered from your statement is that you want 100 floating numbers with 2 decimal places, and the sum of all these numbers should add up to 100.

This certainly is not the cleanest solution, but here goes:

```
$total_days = 100;
$total_amount = 100;
$arr = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i)
{
    $arr[] = rand(0.0, 1000.0);
}
$actual_sum = array_sum($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i)
{
        $y = $arr[$i] * ($total_amount /$actual_sum);
        $arr[$i] = round($y, 2); //round the numbers to 2 dp. Sum of all numbers could be greater than 100.
}
//hack, logic explained below
$maxElementKeys = array_keys($arr, max($arr)); //get max element's key
unset($arr[$maxElementKeys[0]]); //remove the max element from array, now the array contains 99 elements
$arr = array_values($arr); //rebase the keys

for($i = 0; $i < $total_days; ++$i) 
{  
    if($i < ($total_days - 1) )
        $value = $arr[$i]; 
    else 
        $value = $total_amount - array_sum($arr); //to get the 100th number, subtract from 100 to ensure the total always adds up to 100
    $genpackageroi = array(
        'userid' => $userid,
        'pkgid' => $pkgid,
        'pkgcount' => $pkcount,
        'amount' => $value,
        'created_at' => $created_at,
        'updated_at' => $updated_at,
    );
    DB::table('genpackageroi')->insert($genpackageroi);
}
```

The logic here is that round all numbers to 2dps. The total of which would in most cases exceed 100 by a few dps.
Next, get the max random number in the array and remove it from the array to make it an array containing 99 elements. The max number is removed to ensure that the sum of the new array stays below well clear of 100. So, to get the 100th element, get the sum of the new array and subtract that value from 100. Now, the total of all elements of the array and the 100th element that was just calculated should add up to exactly 100, with negligible chance for failure.

Comment: Yes that's what I actually I wants. But here is another issue with this solution. It works fine when I execute it with 100 days and 100 amount, But when I increase the days or amount it gives me the round values till 20 OR 30 lines, after that It gives me the float values with lots of dps, and also the last values are same. Like if the value of float comes from 30th line like 0.645135489 then it goes with the same value to the end of line.

Comment: And another issue is If I add 100 amount with 300 days it gives me the total sum of '191.55' of 100 amount. Which is totaly wrong. It should be exactly 100 OR upto 100 like 100.2 OR so. Overall this works great with 100 of amount and for 100 days. Plz have a look on this.

Comment: @MuhammadNoman let me check and eys of course I assumed 100 would be the max and I even harcoded 99, so that should be changed to `$total -1`. Also do note that the calculation is as it is, I didnt change any part of the calculation. But, let me have a look at it too

Comment: Now I made a little change into your solution and its working perfect. You gave the if($i < 99)'s value manually and what i did to give an amount to the variable first like $total_days  = 365; and then substracted 1 value from the $total_days var like : $total_daysElem = $total_days - 1; and updated the if condition with if($i < $total_daysElem) and $value = $total_amount - array_sum($arr); and its working perfect now. Thanks Sir you gave a good solution

Comment: I will also update the answer, I shoudlnt have hard coded 99 to begin with :)

Comment: yup, you gave an excellent solution and it is now working perfect. I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: By the way I need a little more help about the for loop :) if you don't mind. I can create another question for that. I think you can give a nice solution to that also. That's just a little issue.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: please have a look on this question which i posted now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763060/execute-for-loop-or-foreach-loop-to-update-users-table