# Execute for loop OR foreach loop to update users table

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop, foreach

Actually I wanted to run a loop in which the users data should be updated multiple times. Like i have a query to get the record before:

```
select id, pkgid, userid from lendinglogs where status = 1
And I get the result like this:
-------------------------------
id     userid      pkgid
1      6           1
2      7           2
2      7           2
-------------------------------
foreach ($selectUsers as $row) {

$userid= $row->userid;

//Now I selects the earning value from the table against the userid and pkgid like:

$selectROI = DB::table('genpackageroi')->select('*')->where('userid', '=', $userid)->where('pkgid', '=', $pkgID)->where('pkgcount', '=', $pkgCount)->orderBy('id')->first();

//Returned data

------------------------------------
id     userid      pkgid     amount
1      6           1         0.54
2      7           2         1.23
2      7           2         0.94
-----------------------------------

$value = $selectROI->amount;
//Update users data
$updateUsers = DB::statement("Update users SET earning = '$value' WHERE id = '$userid'");

}
```

Now the users earning should be updated with the amount of 1.23 + 0.94 = 2.17

But when I execute this code the user data updates only one time with only one value like: 1.23, however it should be updated with the amount of 2.17. It means the loop runs for one time only. While I need it to update the user data 2 times I there are two users id which are same but the package ids are different. I mean the user's earning should be updated with the values that are returned from the genpackageroi's table.

Anybody have any idea how to do that?

-----------------------Update-------------------------------------

Query:

```
$selectROI = DB::table('genpackageroi')->select('*')->where('userid', '=', $userid)->where('pkgid', '=', $pkgID)->where('pkgcount', '=', $pkgCount)->orderBy('id')->first();

echo "Userid: ".$selectROI->userid."<BR> Amount: ".$selectROI->amount."<BR>";
```

Result:

```
-------------------------
userid      amount
15          1.08
15          1.83
--------------------------
```

Now we have two user ids and both are same, it is updating the user data one time while it should update two times because we have two values against the same user.

------------------------------------Suggestion By user3532758 ------------------------

Query:

```
$selectROI = DB::table('genpackageroi')->select(DB::raw('sum(amount) as total_amount'))->where('userid', '=', $userid)->where('pkgid', '=', $pkgID)->where('pkgcount', '=', $pkgCount)->groupBy('userid')->first();

dd($selectROI);
```

And the result is:

```
userid        amount
15            199.99999989942
15            399.99999918416
```

Which is totally wrong and unaspected result.

Comment: when you select ROI, you can `groupby user_id` and `sum the amount`. That would give you the total ROI i would assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 2: Your update statement. Add to the existing value in the database.

```
$updateUsers = DB::statement("Update users SET earning = earning + '$value' WHERE id = '$userid'");
```

**Solution 1, which you say returns the wrong results.**
Extending on my comments, I think something like this could work in your case.

Do a SUM on the amount column to get the total amount

```
$selectROI = DB::table('genpackageroi')->select(DB::raw('sum(amount) as total_amount'))->where('userid', '=', $userid)->where('pkgid', '=', $pkgID)->where('pkgcount', '=', $pkgCount)->first();
```

Now `$selectROI->total_amount` should have the both values added up.

Comment: this query is giving me these values  'userid: 15, amount: 199.99999989942 userid: 15, amount:399.99999918416. While It should be like 1.83 + 1.08 = 2.91.

Comment: hmm... can you maybe update question to include pkgcount data as well? Also, if you could do `dd($selectROI)` after query is run, and share a screenshot, it might help get a clearer picture

Comment: here is the screen shot : https://prnt.sc/ucfjuq with dd($selectROI). And pkg count is like if the user has only one package then there will be 100 rows with column value of pkg count 1 for all 100 rows. If the user has two packages than there will be an other set of 100 rows of that package's values and with value of 2 in pkgcount column.

Comment: and here is another screen shot https://prnt.sc/ucfm1x   with this command:      $selectROI = DB::table('genpackageroi')->select('*')->where('userid', '=', $userid)->where('pkgid', '=', $pkgID)->where('pkgcount', '=', $pkgCount)->orderBy('id')->first();  echo "Userid: ".$selectROI->userid."<BR> Amount: ".$selectROI->amount."<BR>";

Comment: hmm let me think about this, btw, I would need to adjust my solution anyways because I missed the duplicated user id in the first select `$selectUsers`

Comment: yes, that's what exactly I wanted to do so. Okay take the time, I can wait :) by the way thanks :)

Comment: Sorry got busy. Updated answer, do give solution 2 a try, Also, would you mind sharing a dump of lendinglogs  and genpackageroi tables, because it feels like I can give you a cleaner solution?

Comment: The second solution works fine. Its now updating the user data as I want. Thanks for the solution Sir.